# Changing unit price for different quantities

Tags: javascript, html, e-commerce, price, discount

I have this price calculator where the price for each item is `2`. I need the price to be `1.8` if the quantity is over `1000`. In another condition it also could be treated as discount, for example if the quantity is bigger than `1000`, then discount `10%`

I've tried using an `if` condition, but I couldn't figure out how to solve this.

```js
function calculate(price) {
  var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value || 0;
  qty = parseFloat(qty).toFixed(2);
  var result = parseFloat(qty * 2).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("result").value = result;

  if (result >= 1000) {
    result = result - 10%
  }
}
```

```html
<form role="form" id="price" name="price">
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="qty" onchange="calculate(qty*2)" value="">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="result" value="" disabled>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the attempt with your `if` condition? If you show us what you tried we can provide some details to teach you why the approach you took can be approved. As it stands, all someone can do here is dump the working code, which doesn't really teach you anything.

Comment: `if (result>=1000) 
            {
                result=result-10%
            }

            }`

i tried this. i dont even sure what am i doing, im new in this world

Comment: Thanks for editing, I've added a working solution for you below

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `10%` isn't a valid term. You need to work out the percentage mathematically and remove it from the total, something like this:

```js
const itemPrice = 2;
const result = document.querySelector('#result');

document.querySelector('#qty').addEventListener('input', e => {
  const qty = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
  const subtotal = itemPrice * qty;  
  const discount = qty > 1000 ? 0.1 : 0; // 0.1 here = 10%
  const total = subtotal - subtotal * discount;
  result.value = total.toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<form role="form" id="price" name="price">
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="qty" value="" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="result" value="" disabled />
  </p>
</form>
```

Note that this logic is intentionally verbose simply for demonstrative purposes. You can make it more succinct if necessary.